# Recursive grep in directory with helm and/or projectile?

Tags: helm, projectile, grep

A recursive grep in a directory should be the simplest thing, but I haven't found the recipe to get it to work yet. I'm juggling between the following commands and am not sure which has the functionality buried within it:

- `helm-find-files`: The problem is this is really bad at finding a directory recursively.
- `projectile-find-dir`: This is great at finding the dir! However despite using helm complete you don't wind up in helm mode, so the `C-u C-s` command doesn't work here.
- `helm-find`: gets the recursion right but targets files, not directories
- `helm-projectile-find-dir`: Seems to be what I want.

Comment: I love ag and ag-mode for that, the silver searcher beats grep with one hand tied to its back :-), don't know how to make it  projectile aware, though

Comment: M-x projectile-ag maybe ? («projectile-prefix» A or «projectile-prefix» a – depending on the version)

Comment: To the original poster: I do not quite understand what is your purpose. projectile-ack and projectile-ag are both great recursive greps within (whole) projectile project. Aren't they what you need?

Answer (score 10):

You have two ways:

- Use `helm-projectile-grep/ack/ag`: You can search for everything starting from project root. Later if you want to save the search results, press `F3` or press `TAB` to switch to action menu and select the 3rd action. To navigate `hgrep` buffer:

  - `C-<down>`: go to next match and open the match.
  - `C-<up>`: go to previous match and open the match.
  - `M-<down>`: go to next match without opening the match.
  - `M-<up>`: go to next match without opening the match.
  - `C-o`: open current match in other window.
  - `RET`: open current match in current window.
- Use `helm-projectile-find-dir` (note the `helm` prefix; you must use proper Helm commands from `helm-projectile` package in general): narrow to a desired directory and press `C-u C-s` to recursively search in that directory. If you don't press `C-u`, it just searches in that directory without going deeper.

Hope that helps.

Comment: You have just enabled me to unlock a huge gain by informing me of this "TAB" action within a projectile search result. Thank you. Thank you, sir.

Comment: The tab key only makes the result open in a buffer, handy, but not what you 2 describe. Also, `helm-projectile-grep` would be perfect enough for me as is, if it would only show the *full* path, instead of only the file name. It's pretty useless if you have hierarchies with a lot of same filenames and similar content, but differ in the parent directory name

Answer (score 6):

> A recursive grep in a directory should be the simplest thing

For a simple recursive grep inside current directory, just: `M-x grep` then, inside the minibuffer: `Run grep (like this): grep -nHr "pattern"`. (notice the -r flag).

You may also be interested by `rgrep`:

> rgrep is an interactive autoloaded compiled Lisp function in
>   `grep.el'.
>
> (rgrep REGEXP &optional FILES DIR CONFIRM)
>
> Recursively grep for REGEXP in FILES in directory tree rooted at DIR.
>   The search is limited to file names matching shell pattern FILES.
>   FILES may use abbreviations defined in `grep-files-aliases', e.g.
>   entering`ch' is equivalent to `*.[ch]'.

Comment: That is not linked to projectile which it should be in the context.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the tools mentioned in the other answers, another cool function is `find-grep-dired` which creates a `dired` buffer containing all files matching a recursive grep pattern.

It just runs `find . \( -type f -exec grep -q -e my-regular-expression \{\} \; \) -ls` and displays the results in a `dired` buffer.

Answer (score 2):

This package has exactly what you are looking for:
https://github.com/syohex/emacs-helm-ag

The command's name is helm-do-ag.

Comment: Can I specify a set of folders where I could search always by default?

Answer (score 1):

You could try `helm-do-grep`. Calling it with a prefix arg gives you a recursive grep, as explained in the [Helm Wiki](https://github.com/emacs-helm/helm/wiki#grepdirectoryrecursively).

> If you want to launch helm-do-grep recursively without starting
>   helm-find-files, do:
>
> C-u helm-command-prefix-key M-g s
>
> NOTE: If you forget to hit C-u before M-g s you can do it after file
>   selection.
>
> You will be prompted for selecting in which category of files to
>   search: Use the wilcard syntax like *.el for example (search in only
>   .el files).
>
> By default, the extension of the file at point is used when the cursor
>   is on a filename. If the cursor is at root of a directory, all the
>   filename extensions found in the directory and not matching
>   grep-find-ignored-files are inserted into the prompt.

Try it like so:

`C-u helm-command-prefix-key M-g s`

Answer (score 0):

`helm-projectile-find-dir` is probably the proper functionality. You can

1. Find a directory as in `projectile-find-dir`
2. But then you finish in Helm mode where you can run `C-u C-s` for a recursive search as desired.