# How to recursively search / grep file contents in a directory / subdirectories in Emacs?

Tags: grep

I'm using Emacs for quite some time and I still somehow fail to understand what is the best way to (recursively) grep for a string within a (project) directory and get the results presented either as a dired buffer or in some even more useful way. Please enlighten me.

Comment: Have you tried out using `helm-projectile-grep` command (if you have helm projectile installed) or `projectile-grep` ?

Comment: I do not know what `helm` or `projectile` is, but if it is a recommended tool, I would install and learn it.

Comment: Yes, projectile is a package that provides an easy way to do what you mentioned in the question with the command `projectile-grep`. Also, I HIGHLY recommend you install `helm` package. I can't imagine running emacs without `helm` and `helm-projectile`. 
You might also be interesting in `helm-ag` package (which provides a helm interface for silver searcher in emacs, which is supposedly faster than grep or ack).

Comment: Now make those comments into a full-fledged answer lol.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to use query-replace from grep/ack/ag output modes?](http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/212/is-there-a-way-to-use-query-replace-from-grep-ack-ag-output-modes)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Recursive grep in directory with helm and/or projectile?](http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/10842/recursive-grep-in-directory-with-helm-and-or-projectile)

Comment: My link points to a question about query replace, but I believe it strongly applies to your question too. My answer to that question uses ag instead of grep to search through the whole project. (I then choose to use wgrep+multiple cursors to replace all the matches.)

Comment: So that the question is more useful and easier to find for future Google and forum searchers, perhaps consider modifying the *title* of the question to include the word **recursively**, and consider limiting the scope -- e.g., **How to recursively grep file contents in a directory  / subdirectories**.  That's just an example -- it could be something else instead.

Comment: While the comments and answers so far have suggested a number of packages to do this in various fancy ways, I don't see from your question why simple `M-x grep` doesn't do what you need.  It let's you give an arbitrary command line, I sometimes use `find` there when I need the recursion.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion about the title. It will take me some time to absorb the knowledge I received here from all of you and find out what works the best for me. Maybe I'm lame or something, but grepping was a long-standing problem for me and I hope my question can help others, too.

Answer (score 24):

Well, since the original question doesn't mention `rgrep`, I'll go ahead and point it out here. This is the simplest option already built into Emacs, and I've found it to be more than sufficient for most things.

From the documentation,

```
Recursively grep for REGEXP in FILES in directory tree rooted at DIR.
```

The search is limited to file names matching shell pattern FILES.

So, for instance, to search all python files beneath my home directory for uses of`some_function`, I would call it with `some_function`, `*.py`, `~/` as the arguments.  Results are displayed in a new buffer.

Comment: Might want to mentioned `find-grep-dired` as well since OP mentioned "results presented either as a dired buffer or..."

Comment: @npostavs I haven't used `find-grep-dired` myself, feel free to add it to the answer.

Comment: I once experimented with the likes of ack and ag, on the assumption that I should be switching from rgrep to something using those, because they were supposed to be better. In the end I stayed with rgrep, because I found no benefit to changing! On the command line there's certainly a case to be made, but in Emacs `rgrep` does such a good job of targeting the search that there were no significant speed differences between them. (I want to say that rgrep was fractionally *faster* in some cases, but I don't remember for sure.)

Comment: Note that `next-error` and `previous-error` can be used to navigate through the result set. I find `M-g M-n` and `M-g M-p` the most convenient of the standard bindings.

Comment: `find-grep-dired` doesn't give me a buffer with cross-referencing links. `rgrep` does it for me and that last suggestion about `next-error` `previous-error` is fantastic! My only quibble is that all the messy command execution output at the start of the buffer.

Comment: correction. `find-grep-dired` does work like this, there was a subtle error in my configuration (`find-ls-option` was being confused by tabs in my `find` implementation's `-ls` output). The output is still quite verbose though so I think I still prefer the `rgrep` approach.

Comment: Thank you, had never heard of `rgrep`. Simple and neat.

Answer (score 17):

I happily use `M-x find-grep-dired` for years. It returns the results as a dired buffer, which you could use.

Comment: I've had some difficulty with getting the cross-reference linking to work with this. It's configuration is quite nasty (`find-ls-option`) and after all that you end up with something that's quite verbose because it doesn't work without having the date before the filename!

Comment: Had never heard of `fing-grep-dired` either, very neat too. Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

Solution 1 (best solution):

Install counsel (https://github.com/abo-abo/swiper/blob/master/counsel.el)

Then `M-x counsel-git-grep`.

No setup needed (git knows the project root and files to exclude). Both `git grep` and `counsel` is efficient.

The project need be managed by git.

counsel requires ivy-mode.

Solution 2:

This solution uses grep and works on any project. It's inferior to the Solution 1 because it's slower and need manual setup. It's also based on ivy-mode.

```
(defvar simple-project-root "~/.emacs.d")
(defun simple-grep ()
  (interactive)
  (unless (featurep 'ivy)
    (require 'ivy))
  (let* ((default-directory (file-name-as-directory simple-project-root))
         (keyword (read-string "Keyword:")))
    (ivy-read (format "Grep at %s:" simple-project-root)
              (split-string (shell-command-to-string (format "grep -rsnI %s ." keyword)) "\n" t)
              :action (lambda (val)
                        (let* ((lst (split-string val ":"))
                               (linenum (string-to-number (cadr lst))))
                          ;; open file
                          (find-file (car lst))
                          ;; goto line if line number exists
                          (when (and linenum (> linenum 0))
                            (goto-char (point-min))
                            (forward-line (1- linenum))))))))
```

You need create .dir-locals.el to setup `simple-project-root`, see https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Directory-Variables.html for technical details

The code in solution 2 is just a prototype. My real implementation is much more complex. See `counsel-etags-grep` in https://github.com/redguardtoo/counsel-etags/blob/master/counsel-etags.el

Summary:

Those are the best two solutions I know.

If any other better solutions exist, they need at least solve below problems to be production-ready,

- how to get the keyword to grep (for example, get keyword from selected region)
- escape the keyword
- if more efficient grep program exist, we should use it (ripgrep, the_silver_searcher/ag, ... etc), or else fallback the default grep
- candidate window should use full width of screen and users can filter candidates interactively (that's why people use ivy or helm)
- we should show the relative path in candidate window
- able to re-use previous grepped result. So previous result should be saved. You can use `ivy-resume` from `ivy` or `helm-resume` from `helm`
- When you save previous grepped result, the context of previous result should also be saved. For example, in the code of of Solution 2. `default-directory` is context. See https://github.com/abo-abo/swiper/issues/591 for more details.
- Extended regular expression should be used because it's simpler and is already used by `counsel-git-grep` and the the_silver_searcher/ag.

Answer (score 4):

Here is an example of a custom grep function that recursively greps file contents (using a regexp for the search term) in a directory and its subdirectories, and displays the results with lines of context before and after.  The built-in `compile.el` and `grep.el` libraries provide for several methods to jump to the location in the file containing the search results.  There is no need to install anything else for this example to work -- all that is needed is a full version of Emacs and a computer that has the `grep` utility installed.  The variable `grep-program` can be adjusted to point to a particular location of the `grep` utility if the default is not sufficient.

```lisp
(defun recursive-grep ()
"Recursively grep file contents.  `i` case insensitive; `n` print line number;
`I` ignore binary files; `E` extended regular expressions; `r` recursive"
(interactive)
  (let* ((search-term (read-string "regex:  "))
         (search-path
           (directory-file-name (expand-file-name (read-directory-name "directory:  "))))
         (default-directory (file-name-as-directory search-path))
         (grep-command
           (concat
             grep-program
             " "
             "-inIEr --color=always -C2"
             " "
             search-term
             " "
             search-path)))
    (compilation-start grep-command 'grep-mode (lambda (mode) "*grep*") nil)))
```

Comment: While the question does not seek how to simultaneously modify multiple files that are returned as results by the above grep function, I find it very helpful to use `multiple-cursors` and `wgrep`.  It makes modifying multiple files in one fell swoop a breeze.  Said libraries, however, would need to be installed if those features are desired.

Comment: What's the advantage of using this over the builtin `rgrep`?

Comment: @npostavs -- I found the built-in `rgrep` to be time-consuming to customize to my preferred regex search criteria, and I chose to hard-code everything in a custom function (which I use several times each day).  If you would like to write-up an alternative answer that describes how to customize `rgrep`, that would be helpful to other forum readers in the future.

Answer (score 4):

I'd like to add another solution to @chen bin's solution which also uses `counsel` (but you don't need to have a project maintained by `git` for this).

You need to install [ag](https://github.com/ggreer/the_silver_searcher) (the silver searcher) and `counsel` provides the command `counsel-ag` which searches the current directory for the entered string.

If you want to search within a project(not just the current working directory), add this to your `.emacs` :-

```
  (defun rag/counsel-ag-project-at-point ()
    "use counsel ag to search for the word at point in the project"
    (interactive)
    (counsel-ag (thing-at-point 'symbol) (projectile-project-root)))
```

This function will use `ag` to recursively search the project root directory.

**Edit**: the above function defaults to the symbol at point for searching. If you do not like that behaviour, replace `(thing-at-point 'symbol)` with `nil`. And if you want the search results in it's own buffer press <kbd>C-c C-o</kbd>

**Edit2**: if you've [`ripgrep`](https://github.com/BurntSushi/ripgrep) installed, you can replace `counsel-ag` with `counsel-rg` in the above function and it'll just as fine :)

Comment: Is `projectile-project-root` useable to find Rails project root?

Comment: Yes, as long as it's a valid projectile project it will work. There was some package called projectile-rails I think.

Comment: Why did you name the function `rag/...` ?

Comment: It's a common style that people often use when writing their own functions(you can see it being done by a lot others if you browse their emacs config). All the functions I defined begin with `rag/` prefix and that makes them easy to find under `M-x` :)

Comment: Ic, that's your name :-)